# Is Web Collect functionality in Marketing Cloud still supported?

Tags: marketing-cloud

Do any of you knows if Web Collect functionality in Marketing Cloud is still supported as of today?

Thank you!

Comment: Yes. Why shouldn't it be? Are you looking for anything specific around it?

Comment: Hi @Lukes Lunow, thanks for your comment. 
I was studying for MC Email Specialist certification and saw a question about that functionality. Since I've never heard of it until today, I was curious to know if this was still used/supported.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The simple answer is yes. Both [**WebCollect**](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_es_email_studio_web_collect.htm&type=0) and [**DEManager**](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_es_demanager.htm) functionality is still supported. I would say that a good majority of it is undocumented or at best poorly documented, but it does still work.

I also would not recommend using these though and instead build your own AMPscript processing page to handle any form inputs instead. This provides the obvious benefit of a fully custom processing and validation endpoint, but it also is a more secure option. I have heard that there potentially are certain security risks tied into using this functionality that can have major repercussions. (I can't really go into details, but let's just say I definitely won't be using it)

Comment: Hi @Gortonington, thanks a lot for your reply. It is, indeed, poorly documented on Salesforce's Help website!